# High battery use by apps under location services. But location mode is set to battery saving

Tags: battery-life, location-services, lg-g3

Under Settings > location in my phone, the apps listed under recent location requests say **High battery use**. However the location mode is set to **Battery Saving (Networks only).** I thought high battery use was only when GPS was on.
Does any one know how to fix this? I have tried turning location off and then on again.

Location history is off

Phone: LG G3 (international)

[image]

Comment: Have you find any solution for this issue?